# Column content to change color based on condition

Tags: php, html, jquery

My 4th column produces two outputs from the PHP that is "complete" and "pending". I want to set a condition that will change "complete" to green, the default color is set to red since default content is "pending".
i.e The text color.

```
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><?php echo $array[0];?></th>
  <td><?php echo $array[1];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $array[2];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $array[3];?></td>
  <td class="status" style="color: red;"><?php echo $array[4];?></td>
```

A jquery code would be much appreciated.

Comment: Specifically, this answer, the question may appear unrelated: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9081787/2181514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ternary operator** to check the condition

```
<?php $color = ($status == 'complete') ? 'green' : red; ?>
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><?php echo $array[0];?></th>
  <td><?php echo $array[1];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $array[2];?></td>
  <td><?php echo $array[3];?></td>
  <td class="status" style="color:<?php echo $color; ?>;"><?php echo $array[4];?></td>
</tr>
```